# Capture all queries running within a timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, duplicates

My application is inserting duplicate records and I'm trying to figure out what causes that. It could be coming from the UI application, some stored proc or a nightly SQL job. I  have looked into everything I can find and can't figure it out.

The table in question can have multiple userId but only one record can be active=1 for a user. So everytime I insert into the table, I update the current record with active=1 to 0 before inserting a new record with active=1.

How can I check where the duplicate values with multiple records of active=1 is happening for a userId?

Comment: SQL Server Profiler?

Comment: Extended events?

Comment: Sounds like a major part of the problem is the table design here. At the very least you seem to be missing a constraint that would prevent multiple rows active for a given user.

Answer (score 1):

> The table in question can have multiple userId but only one record can be active=1 for a user

So put a unique index on userid filtered to active=1,eg

```
use tempdb

drop table if exists foo

create table foo(userid int, active int)

create unique index ak_only_one_active_row_per_userid on foo(userid) where active = 1
go
insert into foo(userid, active) values (1,1)
insert into foo(userid, active) values (1,1)
```

The second insert fails with

```
Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 10
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.foo' with unique index 'ak_only_one_active_row_per_userid'. The duplicate key value is (1).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Then you'll both prevent the duplicates from occurring and know who is attempting to insert duplicates because they'll get errors.